# RxJava - Use flowables async way

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Re-edit : I will use the result of this method to initialize the visibility of some buttons in my view
   The accepted answer seems good in theory but the return value of first method is Flowable> instead of Flowable. Hence I cannot pass it as a parameter to subscription since it requires Flowable but it is Flowable>

Question Before Edit

I am using RxJava to observe a method I am required to call from SDK. Using this method I am trying to make an assertion about the existence of something but I do not know how long the call will take so it is hard for me to say terminate the subscription after x seconds.

```
override fun doesExist(): Boolean {
        var doesExist = false
        var subscription : Subscription
        val flowable = Flowable.just(SDK.searchContact("contact"))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object : FlowableSubscriber<Flowable<List<Contact>>> {

                    override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
                        subscription = s
                    }

                    override fun onNext(t: Flowable<List<Contact>>?) {
                        doesExist = true
                    }

                    override fun onComplete() {
                        Log.d("tagtagcomplete", "tagtagcomplete")

                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                        Log.d("tagtagerror", "tagtagerror")
                    }


        return doesExist
    }
```

So what I want to do is return true if I won't get any result from searchContract method and return false if I get a result. While using observables, I can create a subscription object and call it's methods but I could not figure out how to do it right way with flowables.

My confusion is the following: Method to sdk returns a `Flowable<List<Contact>>>` but in my opinion I need to check if a contact exists only once and stop

Right now my method does not go inside onError, onNext or onComplete. It just returns doesExist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reedit my answer,following return type is you need.

```
fun doesExist(): Flowable<Single<Boolean>> {
    return Flowable.just(Single.just(SDK.searchContact("contact")).map{ it.isEmpty()})
}
```

Comment: Couple of questions - 1) Does this wait for searchContact to search one time. 2)When should I cancel the subscription, or does it cancel itself after some point? I can't cancel the subscription at onComplete as it warns me about the initilization of subscription

Comment: you can cancel it in other place,no in doesExist method

Comment: So how can I make it wait? I was using blockingSubscribe for observables in the previous construct. By the way this one liner seems much nicer and more understandable. I will accept it as the correct answer

Comment: do other operation after search

Comment: you can post more code ,I don't know what you want to do after searched result.

Comment: I have posted the code I want to do after this but I do not know if it will help much

Comment: yes,I've see that and I reedit my answer,please check it.I'm going to bed,any question will be answered at tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted your answer. My concern is that doesExist do not return Flowable<Boolean>, it returns Flowable<Single<Boolean>>. So inside the subscription I cannot pass it as a parameter since it is of type Flowable<Single<Boolean>> instead of Flowable<Boolean>. I am very new to RxJava and could not find a way to convert it. I will update here if I can find it

Comment: Hi, I have already fixed that and accepted your answer. My problem is out of my question's scope so you don't have to answer it. I am trying to assign this value to a MutableLiveData<Boolean> but method returns  Single<Boolean> so I can't assign it. I can change my variable to MutableLiveData<Single<Boolean>> but then I want to assign false to that single value. With non-single boolean I can achieve it with myLiveData.value = false but I could not with single data

Comment: Okay,maybe you should ask a new question in this site.